# jQuery AJAX POST request and database error

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, post

I am sending some data over to be added to a database. However when the database cannot add something for various constraints the error function is not called. How can I show an error if there is a database error?

```
var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
                var lastname = $('#lastname').val();
                var email = $('#email').val();
                var password = $('#password').val();
                var dataString = 'firstname=' + firstname + '&lastname=' + lastname + '&email=' + email + '&password=' + password;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../auth/signup",
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('body').html("<h2>demo created successfully!</h2>");
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        $("body").html("<h2>Error!</h2>");
                    }
                })
```

On the server side:

```
router.route('/signup')
    .post(function (req, res) {
        pg.defaults.ssl = true;
        pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL || 'postgres://...', function(err, client) {
            if (err){
                console.log(err['detail']);
                res.status(500).send('Connection to the database went wrong');
            }
            client
                .query(`INSERT INTO agent (admin, email, password, firstname, lastname)
                VALUES (false, '${req.body.email}', '${req.body.password}', '${req.body.firstname}', '${req.body.lastname}');`, function(err, result) {
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                        res.stauts(500).send(err);
                    }
                });
        });
```

Comment: What is your sever code? Did it send error response? An error response in nodejs would be something like res.status(500).send('Something broke!');

Comment: not really. thanks ill try with that!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your backend API returns status code that is `not in the range of 200-299 or 304`

then only error callback will get fired.